# compiling error 'incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'int (int, int)' to parameter of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]"

Tags: c

This code take input from the user (*characters C,T,B*) and (*int 0-24 and 0-60*)  to calculate the cost of parking based on the type of vehicle the user inputs.

I suspect the error occurs in the function `charged` and because of this I cant print the result in the last line of code where I receive this error

---

*[cquery] incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'int (int, int)' to parameter of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]*

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>



int total_minute_parked (int minute_in, int minute_left)
{
  int minute_parked;
  if (minute_in > minute_left)
    {
      minute_parked = (minute_left  - minute_in + 60);
    }
    else 
      {
        minute_parked = (minute_left - minute_in);
      }
 return minute_parked;     
}

// func calc total hours parked 

int total_hour_parked (int hour_in, int hour_left)
{
  int hours_parked;
  if (hour_left > hour_in)
    {

      hours_parked = abs((hour_left - 1) - hour_in);
    }  
    else 
      {
        hours_parked = abs(hour_left - hour_in);
      }

return hours_parked ;
}

// -------------------funtion to calc charge based off type of vehicle------ 

float charged (char vehicle_type,int total_hour_parked)
{

char C;
char T;
char B;

float temp_charged;

if  (vehicle_type == C) // -------------------------------CAR 
  {
    if (total_hour_parked > 3) 
    {
      float secondary_hour = total_hour_parked - 3;
      temp_charged = secondary_hour * 1.5;
    }
    else 
        {
          temp_charged = 0;
        }
  } 

else if  (vehicle_type == T)   // ------------------------------TRUCK 
  {
    if (total_hour_parked > 2) 
    {
      float secondary_hour = total_hour_parked - 2;
      temp_charged = (secondary_hour * 2.3) + 1.0;
    }
    else {
          temp_charged = 1;
        }
  } 

else if  (vehicle_type == B) // -----------------------------------BUS 
  {
    if (total_hour_parked > 1) 
    {
      float secondary_hour = total_hour_parked - 1;
      temp_charged = (secondary_hour * 3.7) + 2.0;
    }
    else {
          temp_charged = 2;
        }
  } 
return temp_charged;
}

//---------------------- end program upon invalid imput -------------------// 



// --------------------- main that prints results and takes imput -----------//

int main() 

{

  int total_hour_parked (int hour_in,int hour_left);
  float charged (char vehicle_type, int total_hour_parked);
char vehicle_type;
int hour_in = 0;
int minute_in = 0;

int hour_left = 0;
int minute_left = 0;

printf("Please enter the type of Vehicle:"); scanf("%c",&vehicle_type); 

printf("Please enter the hour entered lot:"); scanf("%d", &hour_in);

printf("Please enter the minute entered lot:"); scanf("%d", &minute_in);

printf("Please enter the hour left lot:"); scanf("%d", &hour_left);

printf("Please enter the minute left lot:"); scanf("%d", &minute_left);

printf("------------------------------------\n");

printf("Parking time: %d:%d\n", total_hour_parked(hour_in,hour_left),total_minute_parked(minute_in,minute_left));

printf("Cost %f",charged(vehicle_type,total_hour_parked));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You suspect? Your compiler doesn't tell you exactly what line is causing the error?

Comment: I don't get such error.... however this expression should have fired a warning/error `if  (vehicle_type == C) ` as `C` and other `char`s are not initialized.

Comment: You've got a function called `total_hour_parked` and a function parameter called `total_hour_parked`. That's not a good idea. You might want to use a different name for one of those.

Answer (score 2):

In `main` you do:

```
printf("Cost %f",charged(vehicle_type,total_hour_parked));
```

but there is no variable named `total_hour_parked` in `main` so the compiler thinks that you are trying to pass a function pointer to the **function** `total_hour_parked`

Since the function `charged` expects an integer as second argument you get a message like:

```
expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(int,  int)’
         ^^^^^                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        expected                         actual (i.e. function pointer)
```

Maybe you wanted to do:

```
printf("Cost %f",charged(vehicle_type,total_hour_parked(hour_in,hour_left)));
```

In general you should avoid having identical named variables and functions as it causes confusion.

Another issue is these types of lines:

```
if  (vehicle_type == C)
```

It seems that you want to check if `vehicle_type` is the character `C` so you should do:

```
if  (vehicle_type == 'C')
```